# Check if compiler is Turbo C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, predefined-macro

I am currently dealing with legacy code designed for [Turbo C++](https://turboc.codeplex.com/). To work around Turbo C++'s lack of a `bool` data type, the program contains the following line of code.

```
// Necessary when compiling with Turbo C++
enum bool {false, true};
```

Most C++ compilers fail to run the program with `error: expected identifier before 'bool'`. While I would love to switch to a more recent compiler, I am unfortunately required to maintain this workaround for backwards compatibility.

How can I indicate that this specific line of code should only compile in Turbo C++?

Comment: Look for a *predefined macro*, such as `__TURBOC__`.  I got rid of Turbo C++ when Borland C++ came out, then abandoned it around 2008.  You should use something more recent and free.

Comment: You probably want `__TURBOC__` as  suggested here: http://beefchunk.com/documentation/lang/c/pre-defined-c/precomp.html

Comment: Just curious, who still uses Turbo C/C++ ?  Embedded devices?  Legacy devices that still run DOS?

Comment: Most embedded devices use other professional compilers: Keil, Greenhills, IAR, Microsoft, ARM, Intel and Gnu.  TurboC++ doesn't support modern processors like ARM Cortex, which are used in embedded systems.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch My refusal to use Turbo C++ was why I needed this check to begin with. It allowed me to ignore my professor's hacky-workaround when using any modern compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by [Thomas Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566882/check-if-compiler-is-turbo-c#comment68370499_40566882) and [selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566882/check-if-compiler-is-turbo-c#comment68370618_40566882) in the comments:

```
#ifdef __TURBOC__
    // Only runs if compiler is Turbo C++
    enum bool {false, true};
#endif
```

Source: http://beefchunk.com/documentation/lang/c/pre-defined-c/precomp.html